# In TypeScript, how do I modify a third party interface?

Tags: typescript, interface, ag-grid

At the moment, I'm working with the following `GridOptions`interface:

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f065d96ee682d4c43a7275f35935d122d9faeee6/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/gridOptions.d.ts

According to the API:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

`onFirstDataRendered` should exist on the interface, but it does not.

In my code, I'm using the interface as follows:

```
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid/main";
private gridOptions: GridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
```

How can I modify the interface to make `onFirstDataRendered` available?

Edit:

The API page has the following note:

```
This is done by prefixing the event name with 'on', for instance gridOptions.onCellClicked.
```

You can see, for example, that `gridReady` in the API translates to `onGridReady` in the following code:

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f065d96ee682d4c43a7275f35935d122d9faeee6/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/gridOptions.d.ts

Comment: I failed to find "onFirstDataRendered" in the API. Why do you think it has it? There is "firstDataRendered", though

Comment: Nurbol, please see my edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "firstDataRendered" instead of "onFirstDataRendered"?

Edit:

Hmm. It seems that they have some error, because neither "onFirstDataRendered" nor "firstDataRendered" [does not appear](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f065d96ee682d4c43a7275f35935d122d9faeee6/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/gridOptions.d.ts) in GridOptions interface, unlike they promised [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#properties-and-hierarchy) "All of these grid events are available through the GridOptions interface."

BTW [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f065d96ee682d4c43a7275f35935d122d9faeee6/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/eventKeys.d.ts#L78) you can see event constants to make life a bit easier for you (at least you will not mis-type event name).

In order to extend the interface you have to do this:

```
private gridOptions: GridOptions & {onFirstDataRendered: any} = {}; // "any" because i don't know what type the value should have. I removed the type guard (<GridOptions>) because it is redundant, moreover typeguards are deprecated in favor of "as GridOptions" syntax.
```

P.S. and yes, the other guy said it's a new feature. However it is published on npm (v.19.0.0). But it appears buggy (not in the interface). You should create an issue about that in their github repo.

Comment: With this library, they list the event as `cellClicked` but it's actually `onCellClicked`. It's dumb.

Comment: Hey, @Mary I've updated the answer, please check it out

Comment: @thirtydot definitely stupid design decisions out there